# how to translate this mongodb shell expression into ruby mongo driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb, driver

I have this mongodb shell command

```
db.districts.find({servers:{$exists:true}}, {name:1})
```

That I have a hard time translating into ruby mongo driver syntax.

```
coll = db.collection('districts')
coll.find({"servers"=>{"$exists"=>true}}, {'name'=>1}).to_a
```

But it complains with the error
*** RuntimeError Exception: Unknown options [{"name"=>1}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query syntax should look like following

```
collection.find(selector = {}, opts = {})
```

And query should be -

```
collection.find({
  "servers" => {
    "$exists" => true
  }
}, {: fields => {
    "_id" => 0, "name" => 1
  }
})
```

I did not tested it for `$exists` but should work.

Comment: yes, I got the answer after googling a bit more.  Using the following worked for me selector = {'servers' => {'$exists' => true}} opt={:fields => ["servers"]}